# How do you filter a SharePoint list with a text field?

Tags: sharepoint, search, filter, web-parts

I have a SharePoint list, which is paged. I want to allow the user to enter a search string in a text field and then filter that paged list. Is there a way to do this with a Filter Web Part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

1. Add a Form Web Part to the page with your list view
2. Click Edit -> Connections -> Provide form values to -> "Your List Name"
3. Click Next
4. Choose the column you want to be filtered in the List View Web Part
5. Click Finish

Answer (score 0):

Kit provided you with a straight forward answer. But usually people want to find item that contains substring. For that you can connect the form info as parameters to other webparts, and then filter as substring.

Comment: Can you elaborate more the steps? I am looking for this. And also if any expression like greater than less than can be used.